# Image Adapter + Gallery imaging looping

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I have a problem with one of the applications I'm working on. When I press the gallery button and it starts to load it shows all the pictures but its the same photos in the grid except once pressed, it's not the same image as shown in the gridview. Below is the code that I'm working with along with some photos:

[image] [image]

Here is the code in the Image Adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public Integer[] Tattoos = {
        R.drawable.tattoo1, R.drawable.tattoo2,
        R.drawable.tattoo3, R.drawable.tattoo4,
        R.drawable.tattoo5, R.drawable.tattoo6,
        R.drawable.tattoo7, R.drawable.tattoo8,
        R.drawable.tattoo9, R.drawable.tattoo10, 
        R.drawable.tattoo11, R.drawable.tattoo12,
        R.drawable.tattoo13, R.drawable.tattoo14,
        R.drawable.tattoo15, R.drawable.tattoo16,
        R.drawable.tattoo17, R.drawable.tattoo18,
        R.drawable.tattoo19, R.drawable.tattoo20, 
        R.drawable.tattoo21, R.drawable.tattoo22,
        R.drawable.tattoo23, R.drawable.tattoo24,
        R.drawable.tattoo25, R.drawable.tattoo26,
        R.drawable.tattoo27, R.drawable.tattoo28,
        R.drawable.tattoo29, R.drawable.tattoo30, 
        R.drawable.tattoo31, R.drawable.tattoo32,
        R.drawable.tattoo33, R.drawable.tattoo34,
        R.drawable.tattoo35, R.drawable.tattoo36,
        R.drawable.tattoo37, R.drawable.tattoo38,
        R.drawable.tattoo39, R.drawable.tattoo40, 
        R.drawable.tattoo41, R.drawable.tattoo42,
        R.drawable.tattoo43, R.drawable.tattoo44,
        R.drawable.tattoo45, R.drawable.tattoo46,
        R.drawable.tattoo47, R.drawable.tattoo48,
        R.drawable.tattoo49, R.drawable.tattoo50, 
        R.drawable.tattoo51, R.drawable.tattoo52,
        R.drawable.tattoo53, R.drawable.tattoo54,
        R.drawable.tattoo55, R.drawable.tattoo56,
        R.drawable.tattoo57, R.drawable.tattoo58,
        R.drawable.tattoo59, R.drawable.tattoo60, 
        R.drawable.tattoo61, R.drawable.tattoo62,
        R.drawable.tattoo63, R.drawable.tattoo64,
        R.drawable.tattoo65, R.drawable.tattoo66,
        R.drawable.tattoo67, R.drawable.tattoo68,
        R.drawable.tattoo69, R.drawable.tattoo70, 
        R.drawable.tattoo71, R.drawable.tattoo72,
        R.drawable.tattoo73, R.drawable.tattoo74,
        R.drawable.tattoo75, R.drawable.tattoo76,
        R.drawable.tattoo77, R.drawable.tattoo78,
        R.drawable.tattoo79, R.drawable.tattoo80,
        R.drawable.tattoo81, R.drawable.tattoo82
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Tattoos.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Tattoos[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //This actually is a bad solution, because every time convertView is reused, you will still initialize new ImageView, which is wrong
        //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
        //new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);
        //return imageView;

        //Better solution
        ImageView imageView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
            new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);
            //create new ImageView if it is not present and populate it with some image
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            //re-use ImageView that already exists in memory
        }

        return imageView;
    }


    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private int data = 0;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(ImageAdapter.this.mContext.getResources(), data, 100, 100);
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 70));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The issue is that You're storing reference to ImageView in decoding task, which is not right, because ImageViews get recycled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do You mean by 'gallery button', because there's no code of touch handling in the question.

Even so, I think the issue with Your adapter is in usage of `ImageView` reference. Basically `GridView` should manage views creation and recycling to be re-used for other items (then You'll get that view via `convertView`). So, I would suggest to use bitmap cache like the following:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageAdapter";

    private Context mContext;

    public static final Integer[] TATTOOS = {
        R.drawable.image001, R.drawable.image002,
        R.drawable.image003, R.drawable.image004,
        R.drawable.image005, R.drawable.image006,
        R.drawable.image007, R.drawable.image008,
        R.drawable.image009, R.drawable.image010,
        R.drawable.image011, R.drawable.image012,
        R.drawable.image013, R.drawable.image014,
        R.drawable.image015, R.drawable.image016,
        R.drawable.image017, R.drawable.image018,
        R.drawable.image019, R.drawable.image020,
        R.drawable.image021, R.drawable.image022,
        R.drawable.image023, R.drawable.image024,
        R.drawable.image025, R.drawable.image026,
        R.drawable.image027, R.drawable.image028,
        R.drawable.image029, R.drawable.image030,
        R.drawable.image031, R.drawable.image032,
        R.drawable.image033, R.drawable.image034,
        R.drawable.image035, R.drawable.image036,
        R.drawable.image037, R.drawable.image038,
        R.drawable.image039, R.drawable.image040,
        R.drawable.image041, R.drawable.image042,
        R.drawable.image043, R.drawable.image044,
        R.drawable.image045, R.drawable.image046,
        R.drawable.image047, R.drawable.image048,
        R.drawable.image049, R.drawable.image050
    };

    private Bitmap mHolder = null;
    private static final int CACHE_SIZE = 30 * 1024 * 1024; // 8 MiB cache
    /** Cache to store all decoded images */
    private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mBitmapsCache = new LruCache<Integer, Bitmap>(CACHE_SIZE) {

        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(final Integer key, final Bitmap value) {
            return value.getByteCount();
        }

        @Override
        protected void entryRemoved(final boolean evicted, final Integer key, final Bitmap oldValue, final Bitmap newValue) {
            if (!oldValue.equals(mHolder)) {
                oldValue.recycle();
            }
        }
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
        mHolder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher, null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TATTOOS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return TATTOOS[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //This actually is a bad solution, because every time convertView is reused, you will still initialize new ImageView, which is wrong
        //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
        //new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);
        //return imageView;

        //Better solution
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            //re-use ImageView that already exists in memory
        }

        final Bitmap itemBitmap = mBitmapsCache.get(TATTOOS[position]);

        if (itemBitmap == null || itemBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            Log.e(TAG, position + " is missed, launch decode for " + TATTOOS[position]);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mHolder);
            mBitmapsCache.put(TATTOOS[position], mHolder);
            new BitmapWorkerTask(mBitmapsCache, mContext.getResources(), this).execute(TATTOOS[position]);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, position + " is here for " + TATTOOS[position]);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(itemBitmap);
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    /** AsyncTask for decoding images from resources */
    static class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private int data = 0;
        private final LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mCache;
        private final Resources mRes;
        private final BaseAdapter mAdapter;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> cache, Resources res, BaseAdapter adapter) {
            // nothing to do here
            mCache = cache;
            mRes = res;
            mAdapter = adapter;
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mRes, data, 300, 300);
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(data, bitmap);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.outHeight = 300;
        options.outWidth = 300;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

I've also added 'holder' bitmap for displaying loading of images and avoiding multiple decoding launch for the same resource.

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I fix this java.lang.NullPointerException. I changed the API since I needed API 12 to use your code and I was running API 10.

Comment: LRUCache is available in support library, so API 12 is not necessary.

Comment: It worked! Awesome! I have a question though, when I tap on the image and when it opens I'd like to move to the next image by swiping. How would I be able to accomplish this? Also, could you please tell me what was wrong with the code? I'd like to know in order to learn from my mistakes. Sorry, pretty new to Android Development T_T

Comment: For swiping You can check this project https://github.com/AlexStarc/MM5 (it's different from current question). Regarding the issue - as I mentioned it was in using ImageView references for images decoding. It's not right because ImageViews get recycled by GridView and some reference might become invalid and will be reallly at the different position in the grid.

Comment: I get it now because once it recycles it will just use the same image over and over again right? Thanks for the link and your help!

Comment: Right, it actully will use the same ImageView (not image itself), so by cacing bitmaps You're able to attach right bitmap to right ImageView.