# Popup gridview cell onTOuch

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I have a grid View In which I  am adding Button dynamically.
I am setting OnTouch listener to grid view.
I want when my finger move on the  particular cell then that cell element should get popup 
similar way our android keyboard do.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList<Integer> data;
private GridView gv;

private TextView biggerView = null;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createData();
    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gv.setNumColumns(10);
    gv.setAdapter(new FilterButtonAdapter(data, this));

    gv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                try {
                    int position = gv.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(),
                            (int) event.getY());

                    View v = (View) gv.getChildAt(position);
                    if (v != null) {
                        gv.requestFocus();
                          gv.setSelection(gv.pointToPosition( (int)
                          event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));

                    }

                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                int position = gv.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(),
                        (int) event.getY());
                View v = (View) gv.getChildAt(position);
                if (v != null) {
                    gv.clearFocus();
                    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texttoadd);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tv.getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

private void createData() {
    data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        data.add(i);
    }
}


enter code here
```

> i have write this code  which is giving me the selected item but when item are more then grid is scrolled and after that the am not getting the item which i am selecting

i have figured out that the x and y position is getting change when grid is scrolled 
i may be wrong

please help

Comment: You can check this example https://github.com/AlexStarc/MM5/tree/master/MM5/src/com/sandrstar/android/gallery .

Comment: hay thanks for your reply . but which fie should i check

Comment: You can start from ThumbnailsView. Basic idea - just do proper animation. Jsut checked it again on 4.2 device and it still works.

Comment: i gone through 2-3 files. i am new to android that's why i am  not getting any way will you tell me the specific file where i can get proper answer  thanks

Comment: ThumbnailsView.java. You can launch what project and dedug it.

Comment: i have lunched the project you have done a nice job . in your project you image size increase after you tap on the image i want when i move my finger on grid popup should get displayed  . i have almost done that but the problem is that when the number are button i my grid are more at that time grid automatically get scrolled at that time it is not working properly

Comment: so, Do You want actual popup moving during scroll? I thought the issue is in showing popup.

Comment: yes  do you have any better option p

Comment: You can override Grids onScrollChanged() and update popup position every time, the only issue, that selected item will be to be tracked also.

Comment: the same problem i am facing when there are more textview  i add in grid then grid apply its  own scroll at that time it is diffcult to keep track of which item i have selected .   is there is any way in grid view i  can keep track how much i have scrolled in grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that suggested in the question way of touch position detection might be not effective, because there's more high-level way to obtain scrolling position.

The main ideas of the implementation are the following:

1. Use [onScrollChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to track scroll position at every moment;
2. Display selection as separate view above `GridView`;
3. Track if selected item is visible (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619271/android-listview-mlistview-getchildati-is-null-how-to-solve-it));

So, to obtain proper scroll callback, slightly customized `GridView` is needed:

```
public class ScrollAwareGridView extends GridView {

    /** Callback interface to report immediate scroll changes */
    public interface ImmediateScrollListener {
        void onImmediateScrollChanged();
    }

    /** External listener for  */
    private ImmediateScrollListener mScrollListener = null;

    public ScrollAwareGridView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollAwareGridView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollAwareGridView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

        if (null != mScrollListener) {
            mScrollListener.onImmediateScrollChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param listener {@link ImmediateScrollListener}
     */
    public void setImmediateScrollListener(final ImmediateScrollListener listener) {
        mScrollListener = listener;
    }
}
```

It will be placed in the xml the following way (main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.TestApp.ScrollAwareGridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3" />

    <!-- Selection view -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In above xml there's also selection view presented.

Activity will handle selection of items (however, it might be better to keep selection and scroll tracking logic in separate object (grid adapter or specific grid fragment) in order not to keep grid-specific logic in Activity code):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ScrollAwareGridView.ImmediateScrollListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    /** To start / pause music */
    private ImageView mSelectedImage = null;
    /** position of selected item in the adapter */
    private int mSelectedPosition;
    /** Main grid view  */
    private ScrollAwareGridView mGrid;
    /** Adapter for grid view */
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Show the layout with the test view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSelectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImage);

        mGrid = (ScrollAwareGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

        if (null != mGrid) {
            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

            mGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mGrid.setImmediateScrollListener(this);
            mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(null);
        mSelectedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSelectedPosition = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onImmediateScrollChanged() {
        if (mSelectedPosition >= 0) {
            int firstPosition = mGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // This is the same as child #0
            int wantedChild = mSelectedPosition - firstPosition;

            // Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild will now be 2
            // So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
            if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= mGrid.getChildCount()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get view for desired position, because it's not being displayed on screen.");
                mSelectedImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return;
            } else {
                mSelectedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            // Could also check if wantedPosition is between listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() and listView.getLastVisiblePosition() instead.
            final View selectedView = mGrid.getChildAt(wantedChild);

            if (null != selectedView && mSelectedImage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                // Put selected view on new position
                final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams zoomedImageLayoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mSelectedImage.getLayoutParams();

                // 200 is difference between zoomed and not zoomed images dimensions
                // TODO: Avoid hardcoded values and use resources
                final Integer thumbnailX = mGrid.getLeft() + selectedView.getLeft() - (ImageAdapter.HIGHLIGHTED_GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION - ImageAdapter.GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION) / 2;
                final Integer thumbnailY = mGrid.getTop() + selectedView.getTop() - (ImageAdapter.HIGHLIGHTED_GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION - ImageAdapter.GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION) / 2;

                zoomedImageLayoutParams.setMargins(thumbnailX,
                        thumbnailY,
                        0,
                        0);

                mSelectedImage.setLayoutParams(zoomedImageLayoutParams);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;

        final Bitmap bm = mAdapter.getImage(position);

        // Obtain image from adapter, with check if image presented
        if (bm != null) {
            final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams zoomedImageLayoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mSelectedImage.getLayoutParams();

            // 200 is difference between zoomed and not zoomed images dimensions
            // TODO: Avoid hardcoded values and use resources
            final Integer thumbnailX = mGrid.getLeft() + view.getLeft() - (ImageAdapter.HIGHLIGHTED_GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION - ImageAdapter.GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION) / 2;
            final Integer thumbnailY = mGrid.getTop() + view.getTop() - (ImageAdapter.HIGHLIGHTED_GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION - ImageAdapter.GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION) / 2;

            zoomedImageLayoutParams.setMargins(thumbnailX,
                    thumbnailY,
                    0,
                    0);
            zoomedImageLayoutParams.height = ImageAdapter.HIGHLIGHTED_GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION;
            zoomedImageLayoutParams.width = ImageAdapter.HIGHLIGHTED_GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION;

            mSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
            mSelectedImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            mSelectedImage.setLayoutParams(zoomedImageLayoutParams);
            mSelectedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is `GridView`s adapter. However there's nothing specific in it which related to scrolling tracking (most of code I've reused from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17801815/657487)):

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageAdapter";
    /** For creation of child ImageViews */
    private Context mContext;

    public static final Integer[] IMAGES_RESOURCES = {
        R.drawable.image001, R.drawable.image002, R.drawable.image003, R.drawable.image004,
        R.drawable.image005, R.drawable.image006, R.drawable.image007, R.drawable.image008,
        R.drawable.image009, R.drawable.image010, R.drawable.image011, R.drawable.image012,
        R.drawable.image013, R.drawable.image014, R.drawable.image015, R.drawable.image016,
        R.drawable.image017, R.drawable.image018, R.drawable.image019, R.drawable.image020,
        R.drawable.image021, R.drawable.image022, R.drawable.image023, R.drawable.image024,
        R.drawable.image025, R.drawable.image026, R.drawable.image027, R.drawable.image028,
        R.drawable.image029, R.drawable.image030, R.drawable.image031, R.drawable.image032,
        R.drawable.image033, R.drawable.image034, R.drawable.image035, R.drawable.image036,
        R.drawable.image037, R.drawable.image038, R.drawable.image039, R.drawable.image040,
        R.drawable.image041, R.drawable.image042, R.drawable.image043, R.drawable.image044,
        R.drawable.image045, R.drawable.image046, R.drawable.image047, R.drawable.image048,
        R.drawable.image049, R.drawable.image050
    };

    // TODO: use resources for that sizes, otherwise You'll GET PROBLEMS on other displays!
    public final static int GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION = 300;
    public final static int HIGHLIGHTED_GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION = 500;

    private Bitmap mHolder = null;
    private static final int CACHE_SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 8 MiB cache
    /** Cache to store all decoded images */
    private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mBitmapsCache = new LruCache<Integer, Bitmap>(CACHE_SIZE) {

        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(final Integer key, final Bitmap value) {
            return value.getByteCount();
        }

        @Override
        protected void entryRemoved(final boolean evicted, final Integer key, final Bitmap oldValue, final Bitmap newValue) {
            if (!oldValue.equals(mHolder)) {
                oldValue.recycle();
            }
        }
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
        mHolder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher, null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES_RESOURCES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return IMAGES_RESOURCES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION, GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        final Bitmap itemBitmap = mBitmapsCache.get(IMAGES_RESOURCES[position]);

        if (itemBitmap == null || itemBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            Log.e(TAG, position + " is missed, launch decode for " + IMAGES_RESOURCES[position]);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mHolder);
            mBitmapsCache.put(IMAGES_RESOURCES[position], mHolder);
            new BitmapWorkerTask(mBitmapsCache, mContext.getResources(), this).execute(IMAGES_RESOURCES[position]);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, position + " is here for " + IMAGES_RESOURCES[position]);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(itemBitmap);
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    /**
     * Obtains image at position (if there's only holder, then null to be returned)
     *
     * @param position int position in the adapter
     *
     * @return {@link Bitmap} image at position or null if image is not loaded yet
     */
    public Bitmap getImage(final int position) {

        final Bitmap bm = mBitmapsCache.get(IMAGES_RESOURCES[position]);

        return ((mHolder.equals(bm) || bm == null) ? null : bm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false));
    }

    /** AsyncTask for decoding images from resources */
    static class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private int data = 0;
        private final LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mCache;
        private final Resources mRes;
        private final BaseAdapter mAdapter;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> cache, Resources res, BaseAdapter adapter) {
            // nothing to do here
            mCache = cache;
            mRes = res;
            mAdapter = adapter;
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            // Use sizes for selected bitmaps for good up-scaling
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mRes, data, GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION, GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION);
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(data, bitmap);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.outHeight = GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION;
        options.outWidth = GRID_ITEM_DIMENSION;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```